# Magento 1 Translate Phrase With a Comma

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, localisation

In Magento 1 **how can I translate the following** e.g `echo $this->__("This is it, blablabla");`

How can I escape the comma?

I've tried to do this in the translation file

```
This is it"," blablabla, New translation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can simply do:

```
"This is it, blablabla","translation"
```

Comment: left something for us :)